# Get textarea value and add br and space - JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I just need to show textarea value in another div as a live preview.

clone the textarea value and append to another div

**Need to achieve two things but first thing is partially achieved**

1. When typing enter key then add br tag between texts (Done)
2. When typing space key then add space between texts (If you type space bar multiple times , it shows only single space now)

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ShibinRagh/wn2rogcu/6/)

```js
$('textarea').keyup(function(e){   
//console.log(e)
    let content = e.target.value.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "<br />")
    $('.content').html(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<div class="content">
Live textarea content here
</div>
```

Comment: When I write something with space it's working fine. What is not working for you?

Comment: When you type multiple space bar , it shows only single space @CarstenLøvboAndersen

Answer (score 2):

You can use replaceAll() to replace white spaces :

```
$('textarea').keyup(function(e){   
    let content = e.target.value.replaceAll(" ", "&nbsp;").replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "<br />")
    $('.content').html(content);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `pre` tag to keep de spaces.

```js
$('textarea').keyup(function(e){   
//console.log(e)
    let content = e.target.value.replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g, "<br />")
    $('.content').html("<pre>"+content+"</pre>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

<pre> 
<div class="content">
Live textarea content here
</div>
</pre>
```

Comment: you either need the `<pre>`'s or the `replace()`, not both

Answer (score 0):

just replace your `div` tag to `pre` tag.
and you dont need to use `replace` function also.